# Sending an object a reference to another object that hasn't been created yet...

Tags: java, reference

I'm creating two objects each within their own threads

```
    Conversation c = new Conversation();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(c);
    t1.start();

    HunterCom ns = new HunterCom(c);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(ns);
    t2.start();
```

I need to send the conversation object (c) a reference to the HunterCom object (ns)

Is there anyway to do this? Im strugeling because ns has not been created when I want to send it to c.

Comment: Your code example does not match your description.  The objects are not being created within the new threads.  All of the creation is happening in the currently executing thread.  Some elaboration on why you can't just `c.setHunderCom(ns);` would help with understanding the question.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't wait to start `t1` until after `ns` has been created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want c and ns to be referential to each other - i.e. c has a reference to ns, ns has a reference to c.

If that's what you are asking for, you will need to put a setter in c that allows you to set the HunterCom object:

```
public class Conversation{
  void setHunterCom(HunterCom a)...
}
```

That said, if you are having reference cycles like this, it is generally an indication of an object model that needs review.  If you peel the onion apart, you may be able to find a refactoring that eliminates the circular reference.  This is worth doing, as it'll make your code a lot easier to work with down the road.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a third class that can holds onto references to both:

```
class ComManager {
    // getter and setter for Conversation
    // getter and setter for HunterCom
}
```

Then instantiate this class and pass it as an arg to both of your objects:

```
ComManager com = new ComManager();
Conversation c = new Conversation(com);
HunterCom ns = new HunterCom(com);
```

Now, both objects have a reference to `com`, which has getter methods for both `Conversation` and `HunterCom`, which can be used while each of their threads is running.

2nd option is to change the order of how you're instantiating things - create `Conversation` and `HunterCom` with no arguments, then assign references to each other like this:

```
Conversation c = new Conversation();
HunterCom ns = new HunterCom();
c.setHunterCom(ns);
ns.setConversation(c);
```

There are probably several other similar options as well; hopefully this will give you a starting point to find other patterns and get you what you're looking for.